# No matter what I do the same value is being stored in MySQL table field

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table, with the field ('ad_id').

I store variables in different fields with PHP.

One of these fields, the 'ad_id' field as mentioned above, stores the same exact nr over and over again, no matter what the "REAL" name is in the PHP file.

Example: `$ad_id= 12345;`
When trying to store this, the number 11111 is stored. ALWAYS, no matter what I change the $ad_id variable to.

I even echo the $ad_id variable, and it actually IS 12345, but MySQL stores a value of 11111 anyway.

CODE:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO cars_db 
       (ad_id, area, area_community, price, year, mileage, gearbox, fuel, poster_name, poster_email, poster_tel, poster_password, private_or_company, headline, description, salebuy, total_pics, changeable, hide_tel)
VALUES ('$ad_id', '$area', '$kommun', '$price', '$year', '$mile', '$gearbox', '$fuel', '$name', '$email', '$tel', '$ad_passw', '$priv_or_comp', '$headline', '$ad_text', '$forsale', '$nr_of_pics', '$changeable', '$hide_tel')");
```

---

**Update with MySQL table info**:

```
CREATE TABLE `cars_db` (
 `id` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ad_id` int(13) NOT NULL,
 `area` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
 `area_community` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
 `price` int(9) NOT NULL,
 `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `mileage` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `gearbox` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
 `fuel` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
 `insert_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `poster_name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
 `poster_email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
 `poster_tel` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
 `poster_password` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
 `private_or_company` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `headline` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` text COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
 `salebuy` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `total_pics` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `changeable` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `hide_tel` int(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=134 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci
```

---

**Update again:**

I tried setting the $ad_id=012345678901 (12 digits) and it didn't work. Once again same problem. But then I tried setting $ad_id=555555 and it worked, MySQL stored that information...
The length is the problem I think.
Is there a maximum or something?
Is there hidden decimals I don't know about. If so, how can I round it?

---

**Update string insert into**:
All looks fine. Even the value of the $ad_id is ok, 12 digits, but that's not what's inserted into MySQL, because that's a different nr and it is only 10 digits!

```
- AC
- STEREO
- VINTERDÄCK', 'Säljes', '0', '0', '0')
```

Comment: Post the code that inserts/updates the database. We can't help without looking at your code.

Comment: posted it now... check it plz

Comment: can you also post the output of `DESCRIBE cars_db`

Comment: rageZ what do you mean, output of what?

Comment: ... output of a query which says `DESCRIBE cars_db` (which incidentally looks like a TABLE name, not a DB name.

Comment: Need to see when $ad_id is set.

Comment: in your mysql query tool post this query : `SHOW CREATE TABLE cars_db` it will print the definition. I want to know what kind of constraint you applied to `ad_id`

Comment: @camran: thanks, so last bits missing where do you set the `$ad_id`, also you don't need the quotes since it's a number i.e `VALUES($ad_id, `

Comment: The issue lies with the $ad_id variable being populated in PHP...

Comment: I set the $ad_id in a form, with javascript used to create a random number for each ad...
This number somehow got stucked.
But I echo the $ad_id and it actually has a random nr. But thats not the number mysql wants to set

Comment: I mean got stucked in mysql, the old number that is, which is being set for every ad now on (11111)

Comment: @camran: The only other possibility is that you're executing a different INSERT statement

Comment: Right, it may be set to 12345 at thee time of your echo statement, but if that's not the line immediately preceding this (or if there is concurrency that is not being accounted for) the value of $ad_id may be different.

That said, it looks like your data model could use some work. I understand this is probably and dirty prototype that you wanna knock out the door (and you may not have a lot of experience with this type of thing), but your table structure looks too large for its purpose. I see at least 3 potential tables tied together by relationships in this db so far.

Comment: @camran: can you post the code snippet please

Comment: Read my update again, new info

Comment: Build your SQL string into a variable, and print the variable. $sql = "INSERT ..."; echo $sql; mysql_query($sql);

Comment: ok, check update again philfreo

Comment: @everyone: thanks for the comment and everyone inputs on this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Camran you number is too big
if you take a look at mysql documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html) it says:

```
Type  N byte  min value     max value 
INT   4   -2147483648        2147483647
```

You should generate a smaller random number also if you need that to be random you can use the MySQL `RAND` [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand).

Answer (score 1):

The number 668244234626 is out of range for an integer.  It's being truncated to the max value for an integer, which is 2147483647.

If you run your INSERT statement in a MySQL client, you get this result:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Then if you show warnings:

```
mysql> show warnings;

+---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                        |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'ad_id' at row 1 |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------+
```

I notice you declare `ad_id INT(13)`.  Note that the argument 13 has no effect on the range of values that you can store in the integer.  A MySQL integer data type always stores a 32-bit number, and the value you gave is greater than 2<sup>32</sup>.

If you need to store larger values, you should use `BIGINT`.